# MAX Interval End of first interval - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, intervals

I'm working on getting an interval min and max timestamp (15 second interval) where there is a peak interval value. In some cases there are 2 or more peak intervals, but in that case I only want the first interval values. The problem is when I do the max for interval_end it gives me the timestamp of the latest interval, which is incorrect. Please see screenshot below.

[image: intervals]

The min value of interval will be fine (2023-02-03 15:59:32.975), but the max interval value needs to be **2023-02-03 15:59:47.975)**. I now get the value of 2023-02-03 16:00:17.976, which is wrong.

The code I have is the following:

```
select day,
           interval_start,
           interval_end,
           peak_msgrate_incoming,
           max_peak_incoming_msgrate,
           min(if(peak_msgrate_incoming = max_peak_incoming_msgrate, interval_start, null)) as interval_start_peak_in,
           max(if(peak_msgrate_incoming = max_peak_incoming_msgrate, interval_end, null)) as interval_end_peak_out
from table
group by etc..
```

Can somebody help to get the "first max value" before seeing a null?

Expected output:

[image: output]

Thanks!

Comment: what is the exact output you are expecting ?

Comment: Also, the sample data you have given in the image is incomplete. it doesn't include the day and interval_start columns.

Comment: @PunitGajjar I added the correct input data,, also added the expected output, but the interval_end_peak_in time is offcourse incorrect,, as said in the description